# PHP: Sync (if else) with arrays results

Tags: php, date

[image]

I am trying to sort the days, times and the business status if it is closed or open. I am getting the results but they are not working appropriately as needed. My dates and timings are working fine but my status (if open or close... are not sync accordingly), so  here is my code please see the screenshot. Today is thursday, then the status should show on thursday and rest of the days it should be blank.

please see if you have any views on it:-

```
   <?php
  $datetime = new \DateTime();

  $listItem = array('<li class="active">', '</li>');



  $status = array( "Now Open" ,"Closed",  "Opening Soon",  "Closing Soon", "Open 24 hours", "  ");

  $times = array(
    1 => date( $row_DetailRS1['monO'] ). "  ". date( $row_DetailRS1['monC'] ),
    2 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['tueO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['tueC'] ),
    3 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['wedO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['wedC'] ),
    4 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['thurO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['thurC'] ),
    5 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['friO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['friC'] ),
    6 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['satO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['satC'] ),
    7 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['sunO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['sunC'] ) );



  $html .= "<table class='table table-striped'  border='0' align='center' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='20'>
               <tr>
                 <td>Days</td>
                 <td><span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'></td> 
                 <td>Business Hours</td> 
                 <td><span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'></td>
                 <td>Hours</td>
                </tr>";
  $i = 1;

    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');



  foreach ($times as $key => $value):

      $curDayNum = new \DateTime();
      $cd = $datetime->format('N') + 4;




        if ( $cd  == 1) {

               $timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
               $wopeningTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['monO'] );
               $closingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['monC'] );
               $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
               $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
               $curDay = date('l');




               if ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[1];
                   }


                   elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[2];
                   }

                   elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[3];
                   }

                   elseif  ($openingTime == " "  && $closingTime == " " ) {
                       echo "Open 24 Hours";
                   }

                   // show the checkout button
                   else {
                      $s = $status[0];
                   }
               }


               else
               {
                   $s = $status[5];
               }








               if ( $cd  == 2) {

               $timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
               $wopeningTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['tueO'] );
               $closingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['tueC'] );
               $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
               $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
               $curDay = date('l');




               if ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[1];
                   }


                   elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[2];
                   }

                   elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[3];
                   }

                   elseif  ($openingTime == " "  && $closingTime == " " ) {
                       echo "Open 24 Hours";
                   }

                   // show the checkout button
                   else {
                      $s = $status[0];
                   }
               }


               else
               {
                   $s = $status[5];
               }



                if ( $cd  == 3) {


               $timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
               $openingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['wedO'] );
               $closingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['wedC'] );
               $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
               $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
               $curDay = date('l');



             if ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[1];
                   }


                   elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[2];
                   }

                   elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[3];
                   }

                   elseif  ($openingTime == " "  && $closingTime == " " ) {
                       echo "Open 24 Hours";
                   }

                   // show the checkout button
                   else {
                      $s = $status[0];
                   }
               }

               else
               {
                   $s = $status[5];
               }



                  if ( $cd  == 4) {


               $timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
               $openingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['thurO'] );
               $closingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['thurC'] );
               $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
               $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
               $curDay = date('l');



             if ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[1];
                   }


                   elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[2];
                   }

                   elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[3];
                   }

                   elseif  ($openingTime == " "  && $closingTime == " " ) {
                       echo "Open 24 Hours";
                   }

                   // show the checkout button
                   else {
                      $s = $status[0];
                   }
               }

               else
               {
                   $s = $status[5];
               }




                  if ( $cd  == 5) {

               $timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
               $wopeningTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['friO'] );
               $closingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['friC'] );
               $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
               $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
               $curDay = date('l');




               if ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[1];
                   }


                   elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[2];
                   }

                   elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[3];
                   }

                   elseif  ($openingTime == " "  && $closingTime == " " ) {
                       echo "Open 24 Hours";
                   }

                   // show the checkout button
                   else {
                      $s = $status[0];
                   }
               }


               else
               {
                   $s = $status[5];
               }



                  if ( $cd  == 6) {

               $timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
               $wopeningTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['satO'] );
               $closingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['satC'] );
               $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
               $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
               $curDay = date('l');




               if ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[1];
                   }


                   elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[2];
                   }

                   elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[3];
                   }

                   elseif  ($openingTime == " "  && $closingTime == " " ) {
                       echo "Open 24 Hours";
                   }

                   // show the checkout button
                   else {
                      $s = $status[0];
                   }
               }


               else
               {
                   $s = $status[5];
               }




                  if ( $cd  == 7) {

               $timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
               $wopeningTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['sunO'] );
               $closingTime = date( $row_DetailRS1['sunC'] );
               $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
               $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
               $curDay = date('l');




               if ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[1];
                   }


                   elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[2];
                   }

                   elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
                       $s = $status[3];
                   }

                   elseif  ($openingTime == " "  && $closingTime == " " ) {
                       echo "Open 24 Hours";
                   }

                   // show the checkout button
                   else {
                      $s = $status[0];
                   }
               }


               else
               {
                   $s = $status[5];
               }










    $m = $datetime->format('N');


      $html .= "<tr>";
      $html .= "<td>". $datetime->format('l')."</td>";
      $html .= "<td>  <span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'> </td>";
      $html .= "<td>".$times[$m]."</td>";
       $html .= "<td>  <span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'> </td>";
      $html .= "<td>".$s."</td>";
      $html .= "</tr>";


      $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));



      $i++;




  endforeach;
  $html .= "</table>";
  echo $html;



 ?>
```

Comment: Repeating all that code for each day of the week? You should use an array where the day of week is the key, so you don't have to do that.

Comment: You should put the check for Open 24 Hours first, because comparing the current time with empty strings won't give you the desired results.

Comment: Why are you adding `4` to `$datetime->format('N')`?

Comment: hello Barmar, i did +4 for some test, if I dont add then it jumps on sunday, so to see what exactly it does, I added 4 to that code and forgot to remove it

Comment: then do I have to create an array for the weekdays ( $weekdays = array (1 => "Monday", 2 => "Tuesday" and so on...)? How will I combine this array with my times array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting strings into `$time`, put the open and close times for each day. Then you can use it in the loop to compare with the current time.

Also, the variable that just apply to the current time should be set outside the loop, since they don't change.

```
$times = array(
    1 => array('day' => 'Monday', 'open' => date( $row_DetailRS1['monO'] ), 'close' => date( $row_DetailRS1['monC'] ),
    2 => array('day' => 'Tuesday', 'open' => date( $row_DetailRS1['tueO'] ), 'close' => date( $row_DetailRS1['tueC'] ),
    3 => array('day' => 'Wednesday', 'open' => date( $row_DetailRS1['wedO'] ), 'close' => date( $row_DetailRS1['wedC'] ),
    4 => array('day' => 'Thursday', 'open' => date( $row_DetailRS1['thurO'] ), 'close' => date( $row_DetailRS1['thurC'] ),
    5 => array('day' => 'Friday', 'open' => date( $row_DetailRS1['friO'] ), 'close' => date( $row_DetailRS1['friC'] ),
    6 => array('day' => 'Saturday', 'open' => date( $row_DetailRS1['satO'] ), 'close' => date( $row_DetailRS1['satC'] ),
    7 => array('day' => 'Sunday', 'open' => date( $row_DetailRS1['sunO'] ), 'close' => date( $row_DetailRS1['sunC'] ) );
```

Then you can combine all those `if` statements into a single block.

```
$cd = $datetime->format('N'); // don't add 4

$timenow =     date("H:i:s", time());
$curDay = date('l');

// Create an array of day numbers that start with current day and loops around
$day_order = array_merge(range($cd, 7), range(1, $cd-1));

foreach ($day_order as $daynum) {
    $oc = $times[$daynum];
    $openingTime = $oc['open'];
    $closingTime = $oc['close'];
    $openingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($openingTime)-3600);
    $closingSoon = date('H:i:sA', strtotime($closingTime)-3600);
    if ($cd == $daynum) {
        if ($openingTime == ' ' && $closingTime == ' ') {
            $s = 'Open 24 hours';
        elseif ($timenow < $openingSoon || $timenow > $closingTime ) {
            $s = $status[1];
        }
        elseif  ($timenow > $openingSoon && $timenow < $openingTime ) {
            $s = $status[2];
        }
        elseif  ($timenow > $closingSoon && $timenow < $closingTime ) {
            $s = $status[3];
        } else {
            $s = $status[0];
        }
    } else {
        $s = " ";
    }

    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td>". $oc['day']."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>  <span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'> </td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$openingTime." ".$closingTime."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>  <span class='white-text' style='margin-right: 3em;'> </td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$s."</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar,  I tried doing the code as suggested by you, but I am not able the sync the status with the day. On the table, as today is thurs and it appears on first line, but the status goes on the 4th line with sunday)

Comment: I don't see how that can be. The code clearly only sets `$s` to the status when `$cd == $daynum`.

Comment: Can you add `var_export($row_Details);` to the question, so I can make a working demo?

Comment: sure, where do i add the var_export($row_details); or where do i write this. Sorry I am aint that good in coding :(

Comment: Put it after you assign to `$row_Details`.

Comment: Hi, I added that line after the $row_details

Comment: Great. I wanted you to post the output in the question so I can copy it to a demo.

Comment: I see the code is working, however, my day is not rotating. As today is Thurs it should appear right on the top  in the  first row of the table and then friday and so on.... tomorrow is fri so fri comes on top and then rest of the days...

Comment: OK, I've changed my answer. See the `$day_order` variable.

Comment: Because the variable is `$row_DetailRS1`, not `$row_details`.

Comment: Thanks Champ!!! it does work now...., if I want to check if suppose today is friday and want to see it the status and the time sync with it. How can I do it? or else I will have to wait for tomorrow lol

Comment: It all starts from `$datetime`. Whatever date that's set to will be treated as the current date.